# show hour and show page corresponding

Tags: php

I would like show hour time from Fort de France, Martinique.(utc-4)

```
<?php
$hour = date("G");
readfile("./UV/".$hour.".php");
// it's 4hours show 4.php
?>
```

Could you help me ?

Comment: You need to be more specific about what the problem is

Comment: I want show an include php by the time.
For example, if it's 16hours it's showing include 16.php // If is 5hours showing include 5.php

But my php code doesn't work

Comment: What doesn't work?!

Comment: Read the how to ask, https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Im not sure if this is a problem or something, perhaps you need guidance.

IMO you might want to transform the timezone date() if you are not getting the hour you want. An example:

```
date_default_timezone_set("America/Argentina/Mendoza");
$hour = date("G");
echo $hour;
```

More info in http://php.net/manual/en/timezones.php

Second, you might be looking for include() instead of readfile().

https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_includes.asp